# Hide On Account Option - span value

Tags: jquery

Hi I am trying to hide the value "On Account" when it loads on the following page: /payment/invoices

[image: image of view]

Please see the code for that area:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-method-selection">
      <label class="radio">
        <span class="rdb">
          <input data-name="On Account" data-total-amount="$6.36" id="36a83d45-975c-42ee-9bdf-84335e056793" name="MethodId" tabindex="1" type="radio" value="36a83d45-975c-42ee-9bdf-84335e056793">
          <ins><!----></ins>
        </span>
        <img class="method-img" src="/content/files/icons/ptl.png" alt="On Account">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td class="col-method-name">
      <label for="36a83d45-975c-42ee-9bdf-84335e056793" class="method-title">On Account</label>
    </td>
    <td class="col-method-cost">
      <span class="currency-sign font-lighter">$</span>
      <span class="cell-price-value">0.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col-method-selection">
      <label class="radio">
        <span class="rdb">
          <input checked="checked" data-name="Credit Card" data-total-amount="$6.36" id="3a16ff33-e2ca-441a-9619-80397ff1cd44" name="MethodId" tabindex="1" type="radio" value="3a16ff33-e2ca-441a-9619-80397ff1cd44">
          <ins><!----></ins>
        </span>
        <img class="method-img" src="/content/files/icons/visa.png" alt="Credit Card">
      </label>
    </td>
    <td class="col-method-name">
      <label for="3a16ff33-e2ca-441a-9619-80397ff1cd44" class="method-title">Credit Card</label>
    </td>
    <td class="col-method-cost">
      <span class="currency-sign font-lighter">$</span>
      <span class="cell-price-value">0.00</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: One thing i need to clarify. I need t hide this through a jquery, script or css. i dont have access to source code but can inject into the header

Answer (score 0):

Try targeting something known that should not change depending on the transaction. Then use it to hide the whole row.

My idea is something like this:

```
$(document).find("[data-name='On Account']").closest("tr").hide();
```

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thank you!

Comment: <script>
 var url = window.location.href;
 if (url == 'https://beta.ptlusa.com/payment/invoice')
$(document).find("[data-name='On Account']").closest("tr").hide();
</script>

Comment: The "payment information" markup probably isn't there on page load. You will have to find what is the event that brings this markup in DOM... I can't tell. Possibly a click on something specific.